# Use 'exec' to log all output, stop, and then re-attach to the same FDs/Named Pipe

Tags: bash, named-pipes, file-descriptor

update: I think the below code may be headed in the wrong direction -- but the question remains, can I open a pipe to log all output (file&console), pause that log and log to a new log (new file&console), and then re-attach to the FD for the original logger just by moving FDs around and not re-opening the original log file

Trying to improve my knowledge of FDs in bash. I'm trying to log all output of the main "meta" `test.sh` -- but log to a different file when I get to "sections" -- e.g. functions, sourced scripts, etc. And then go back to appending to the "meta" log.

I know I could pretty easily accomplish this with subshells -- or by opening the 'meta' log again and append from there, but can anyone help accomplish this by switching FDs around?

```
#!/bin/bash

rm *.log
NAMED_PIPE="$(mktemp -u /tmp/pipe.XXXX)"
mknod $NAMED_PIPE p
tee <$NAMED_PIPE "./meta.log" &

section () {
  echo SECTION: stdout
  echo SECTION: stderr >&2
}

# link stdout->3 & stderr->4 and save stdout & stderr
exec 3>&1 4>&2 &> "$NAMED_PIPE"
echo METAstr: stdout
echo METAstr: stderr >&2

# restore stdout & stderr
exec 1>&3 2>&4
# sleep 1     # I think an additional delay prevents the possible race condition I'm seeing
# exec 1>&3- 2>&4- ... I think this would restore but close 3 & 4?
# do I need another named pipe here?
section 2>&1 # | tee section.log

# re-link to same pipe
exec 3>&1 4>&2 &> "$NAMED_PIPE"
echo METAend: stdout
echo METAend: stderr >&2
```

Without trying to log 'section' all the meta output gets printed after the return of the script:

```
-bash-4.2# ./test.sh
SECTION: stdout
SECTION: stderr
-bash-4.2# METAstr: stdout
METAstr: stderr
METAend: stdout
METAend: stderr
```

And trying to log 'section' I think fouls up my FDs so the following exec hangs me up:

```
-bash-4.2# ./test.sh 
METAstr: stdout
METAstr: stderr
SECTION: stdout
SECTION: stderr
```

EDIT1:

Contents of `meta.log` after running the script without trying to `tee section`:

```
[root@master tmp]# cat meta.log 
METAstr: stdout
METAstr: stderr
METAend: stdout
METAend: stderr
```

It logs the ending messages, the `tee` does not exit until the script does

EDIT2:
Revision of EDIT1. I think It's a race condition. I think the FDs are *being* closed -- but they're not closed by the time the final echo commands happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was just going to write the same thing. It's a race condition. The second exec closes the writing end in your process, signalling an EOF to tee. tee will want to exit when it gets the EOF. If it does exit by the time you call the last exec, the last exec will block. If it hasn't exited yet at that point, it will not block, because a reading end of the FIFO will still be open.

Any delay will make it more likely tee will have exited by that time.
Spawning a process makes it very likely. I found with stracing (which slows the program down a little) it's about 50/50.

Comment: Exactly. I can get closer -- but then I kick off an endless loop of `stdin` being piped to `tee` and the output from that being sent right back to `tee`